# Table is not shown in the app using TableLayout

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am not able to see the table in the app when ran in emulator.
I am using TableLayout.

Pasting my code below for your reference:

```
package com.example.tablelayoutapp;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    String companies[] = {"Google", "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung",
            "Google", "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung",
            "Google", "Windows", "iPhone", "Nokia", "Samsung"};
    String os[] = {"Android", "Mango", "iOS", "Symbian", "Bada",
            "Android", "Mango", "iOS", "Symbian", "Bada",
            "Android", "Mango", "iOS", "Symbian", "Bada"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addHeaders();
        addData();
    }

    private TextView getTextView(int id, String title, int color, int typeface, int bgColor) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setId(id);
        tv.setText(title.toUpperCase());
        tv.setTextColor(color);
        tv.setPadding(40, 40, 40, 40);
        tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, typeface);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
        tv.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        tv.setOnClickListener(this);
        return tv;
    }

    @NonNull
    private TableLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 2);
        return params;
    }

    @NonNull
    private TableLayout.LayoutParams getTblLayoutParams() {
        return new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * This function add the headers to the table
     **/
    public void addHeaders() {
        TableLayout tl = findViewById(R.id.table);
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        tr.addView(getTextView(0, "COMPANY", Color.WHITE, Typeface.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
        tr.addView(getTextView(0, "OS", Color.WHITE, Typeface.BOLD, Color.BLUE));
        tl.addView(tr, getTblLayoutParams());
    }

    /**
     * This function add the data to the table
     **/
    public void addData() {
        int numCompanies = companies.length;
        TableLayout tl = findViewById(R.id.table);
        for (int i = 0; i < numCompanies; i++) {
            Log.d("Companies",companies[i]);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
            tr.addView(getTextView(i + 1, companies[i], Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)));
            tr.addView(getTextView(i + numCompanies, os[i], Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)));
            tl.addView(tr, getTblLayoutParams());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        TextView tv = findViewById(id);
        if (null != tv) {
            Log.i("onClick", "Clicked on row :: " + id);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on row :: " + id + ", Text :: " + tv.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Had gone through other similar posts in stackoverflow ,but was not helpful to me.

It just shows a blank screen when the app is run in emulator.

It will be great if you can help in resolving the issue.

The activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The `TextView`s added to the `TableRow`s need to have `TableRow.LayoutParams` set on them, not `TableLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: `tv.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());` – The `LayoutParams` you're setting on the `TextView`s are coming from the `getLayoutParams()` method, not `getTblLayoutParams()`.

Comment: @MikeM. changed the following code to use TableRow instead of TableLayout for the getTblLayoutParams method. But still facing the same issue. Hope I have changed at the correct place.

`
private TableRow.LayoutParams getTblLayoutParams() {
        return new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }`

Comment: code of `addHeaders` and `addData` will be helpful, please edit in your question, i you think didn't add any row to this table

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan They're there. Scroll down.

Comment: @MikeM. lol sorry i didn't notice the bar

Comment: @Sabkan I'm not sure if you saw my comment above, but you want to change the `getLayoutParams()` method, not `getTblLayoutParams()`. Doing just that, your code works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/feAdq.jpg.

Comment: @MikeM.it worked fine. Thanks.